# Ionic version 3 segment button binding error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Ionic version 3 segment button binding error.**

---

**UPDATE:**

**NOTE:** THIS HAPPENS WHEN WE USE TWO PAIR OF **ion-segment** IN A SINGLE PAGE.
IF I REMOVE ONE AND MAKE THAT NORMAL BUTTON's - THE OTHER ONE WORKS AS EXPECTED.

**Can't we use two 'ion-segment' in a single page ..?**

---

**Anyone can repeat error** in just 2 steps:

**CASE - 1 :**

*1. Click over second button (PHONE).*

*2. Again click over first button (EMAIL).*

**CASE - 2 :**

*1. Click over first button (EMAIL).*

*Then, it shows both the button selected.*

Same thing happens with segment button ( English / हिन्दी )

**A) FOR DEMO : CHECK LINK [ https://youtu.be/aJ30P0d3RuM ]**

**B) CODE SNIPPET :**

```js
<ion-content padding class="login-content-wrap">
 <div *ngIf="isSignin" class="login-content-inner">
  <h2 text-center padding margin-top margin-bottom>
   <strong>{{ "WELCOME-TO-CYS" | translate }}</strong>
  </h2>
  
  <ion-buttons  text-center margin-top>
   <button ion-button outline padding full 
    (click)="redirectToUserMenuPage(user.email, user.phoneNumber)">
    {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.OPEN-MENU" | translate }}
   </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  
  <ion-buttons  text-center margin-top>
   <button ion-button outline padding full 
    id="sign-out-button" 
    (click)="signout()">
    {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.LOGOUT" | translate }}
   </button>
  </ion-buttons>
 </div>
 
 <div *ngIf="!isSignin" class="login-content-inner">
  <h2 text-center padding margin-top margin-bottom>
   <strong>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.LOGIN" | translate }}</strong>
  </h2>
  
  <div padding>
   <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="loginWith" color="dark">
    <ion-segment-button value="email">
     {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.EMAIL" | translate }}
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="phone">
     {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.PHONE" | translate }}
    </ion-segment-button>
   </ion-segment>
  </div>
  
  <div [ngSwitch]="loginWith">
   <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'phone'">
    <ion-item>
     <ion-label stacked>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.PHONE-NUMBER" | translate }}</ion-label>
     <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="phoneNumber" 
       placeholder='{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.ENTER-10-DIGIT-PHONE-NUMBER" | translate }}' max="10"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    
    <div margin-top id="recaptcha-container"></div>
    
    <ion-buttons  text-center margin-top>
     <button ion-button outline padding full
      [disabled]="true"
      id="sign-in-button" 
      (click)="signInNew(phoneNumber)">
      {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.LOGIN" | translate }}
     </button>
    </ion-buttons>
   </ion-list>
   <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'email'">
    <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (submit)="loginUser()" novalidate>
    
     <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.EMAIL" | translate }}</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder='{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.ENTER-EMAIL-ADDRESS" | translate }}'
       [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.email.valid && loginForm.controls.email.dirty"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item class="error-message" 
      *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.email.valid  && loginForm.controls.email.dirty">
      <p>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.PLEASE-ENTER-A-VALID-EMAIL" | translate }}</p>
     </ion-item>
     
     <ion-item>
      <ion-label stacked>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.PASSWORD" | translate }}</ion-label>
      <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder='{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.ENTER-PASSWORD" | translate }}' 
       [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls.password.valid && loginForm.controls.password.dirty"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item class="error-message" 
      *ngIf="!loginForm.controls.password.valid  && loginForm.controls.password.dirty">
      <p>{{ "LOGIN-PAGE.PASSWORD-ERROR-MASSAGE" | translate }}.</p>
     </ion-item>
     
     <button ion-button block type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
      {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.LOGIN" | translate }}
     </button>
    </form>
    <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToSignup()">
      {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.CREATE-A-NEW-ACCOUNT" | translate }}
    </button>
    
    <button ion-button block clear (click)="goToResetPassword()">
      {{ "LOGIN-PAGE.I-FORGOT-MY-PASSWORD" | translate }}
    </button>
   </ion-list>
  </div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
 <div padding-bottom padding-left padding-right>
  <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="language" color="dark">
   <ion-segment-button value='en' (click)="translateTo('en')">
    English
   </ion-segment-button>
   <ion-segment-button value='hi' (click)="translateTo('hi')">
    हिन्दी
   </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
 </div>
</ion-footer>
```